# Find values in array of object with another array of strings

Tags: javascript

Requirement - I would like to fetch labels from the array of object if the id exists which will be fetched from another array. If that id don't exists, I would like to return that id from the second array.

```
var objectVar = [{ id: '1', label: 'One' }, { id: '2', label: 'Two' }, { id: '3', label: 'Three' }];
var arrVar = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

Here, as 1,2,3 exists I would like to return the labels of it and since 4 doesn't exist in array of object, I would like to return 4. This can be stored in a new Array.

Expected result might look like this -

```
result = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', '4'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let objectVar = [{ id: '1', label: 'One' }, { id: '2', label: 'Two' }, { id: '3', label: 'Three' }];
let arrVar = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
let output = arrVar.map(a => {
    let matched = objectVar.filter(x => x.id == a);
    if(matched.length > 0) {
        return matched[0].label;
    }
    return a;
});
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to return something for each value in `arrVar`, so you probably want [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The function we'll apply to each item will check if the item exists as an `id` in `objectVar`.

We'll use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search `objectVar` for the object with a matching `id`.

We'll use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to choose whether to return the `found` object's `label` or our `arrVar` number.

```js
var objectVar = [
  { id: '1', label: 'One' }, 
  { id: '2', label: 'Two' },
  { id: '3', label: 'Three' }
];
var arrVar = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

const output = arrVar.map(i => {
  let found = objectVar.find(o => o.id === i);
  return found ? found.label : i;
});

console.log(output);
```

---

This approach is nearly twice as fast as the other proposed answers in a single run. The mapper function approach might be faster if you have to repeatedly test new `arrVar` arrays against `objectVar`.

[image: JSBench.me run showing the runs in the table below]

| Approach | Ops/s | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mapper function | 3,237,444.05 | 37.43% slower |
| `Array#map`, `Array#find` | 5,174,453.56 | Fastest |
| `Array#filter` | 3,453,123.01 | 33.27% slower |

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapper object which maps `id` to the `label`

```js
const objectVar = [{ id: '1', label: 'One' }, { id: '2', label: 'Two' }, { id: '3', label: 'Three' }],
      arrVar = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
      labelMapper = Object.fromEntries(objectVar.map(o => [o.id, o.label])),
      output = arrVar.map(n => labelMapper[n] ?? n)

console.log(output)
```